# Generate database from data model

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-4, sql-server-express

I work with .net4. I've created an ADO.NET Entity Framework data model and add new entity with `scolre` property.

I've created a `Database1.mdf` with a data set.

Now I click on `Generate database from model` -->

```
select `Database1ConnectionString` --> 
create  `Model1.edmx.sql`
```

Now when I click on `Execute sql` -->

```
servername=`username\SQLEXPRESS` -->
```

Click on `connect`

I get an error:

> Database 'Database1' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly.

Why?

Comment: Did you try creating Database1 manually and seeing if it kicks off afterwards?

Comment: Most likely, you've created a "stand-alone" `.mdf` file which **isn't** attached to the SQL Server Express instance - so running a SQL against it won't work. To fix this: (1) fire up SQL Server Management Studio (Express), (2) click on Object Explorer > Databases > Attach Database and find your `.mdf` file and attach it to the server instance. Then try again running your script.

Answer (score 0):

Select a corresponding template in the model properties window. Then right-click on the diagram and run the Create Database from Model wizard by choosing **Generate Database from Model** from the popup menu.

[image: Generate Database from Model]

**Note:**
The default schema name for Microsoft SQL Server database is `dbo`. Don't forget to change it to the necessary one before the code generation.
Here is a DDL script generated for the current model.

[image: Generate Database Wizard - Summary and Settings]

As a result of these steps you will obtain a valid database-specific DDL script. You can run this script against your database to create a valid database schema.